# how to find standard deviation of pandas dataframe column containg list in every row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

i have an pandas dataframe

dd1=

```
     A   B   C    D   E    F   Result
     10  18   13  11  9   25  []
      6  32   27  3  18   28  [6,32]
      4   6   3   29  2   23  [29,35,87]
```

now i want to find std of result column by adding C column value with Result column 1st value then 2nd value of result column with C column value and so on.. and i want add that result of std  and store in another column.

i want to pass  the value to std function like this

```
for 1st row :- it will pass because it is empty.

for  2nd row :- std([6,27])=14.84,std([32,27])=3.53
```

after finding std just add that value and store in output column like (14.84 + 3.53)=18.37

```
for 3rd row :-  std([29,3])=18.38,std([35,3])=22.62,std([87,3])=59.39
```

output like this:-  dd1=

```
     A   B   C    D   E    F   Result   output
     10  18   13  11  9   25  []           []
      6  32   27  3  18   28  [6,32]       18.37
      4   6   3   29  2   23  [29,35,87]    100.39
```

Comment: np.std([6,27]) gives me 10.5. am I missing something?

Comment: There are 2 types of std sample standard deviation and population standard deviation.. I think you are calculating with sample standard deviation.  Just try with population standard deviation you will get the value.. @MEdwin

Comment: @vishwajeet see @hacker315 answer below - I get the expected results using that. If you want it to create a new column, then just replace `dd1.apply(l, 1)` with `dd1['output'] = dd1.apply(l, 1)`

Comment: i am not getting output like i want. the code which have given below is not able to do addition of std ..@Prebsus or @peterSmith

Comment: @vishwajeet standard deviation of 6.27 is not 14.84 and of 32,27 is not 3.53 ... Please check..

Comment: please  refer this site [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-statistics-stdev/] @hacker315

Comment: @vishwajeet Did you add the `ddof=1`argument to the`np.std` like I suggested in my comment to @hacker315 post?

Comment: yes  i add that part of code  @Prebsus

Comment: @vishwajeet just to clarify, the answer from hacker315 gives exactly what you are giving in your example. What do you mean by 'not able to do addition of std'

Comment: Thank you now its working. @Prebsus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `lambda` and `apply`:

```
l = lambda x: sum([np.std([x['C'], i], ddof=1) for i in x['Result']])
dd1['output'] = dd1.apply(l, 1)
```